# 「明細を追加」ボタンを押下して、一定数の行数を超えたら、「ボタン」を非表示にしたいです。

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

現在、Railsアプリを製作しています。
そのアプリの中で以下のように「明細を追加」ボタンを押下してtableの行を追加していくのですが、行数が5行を超えたら、「明細を追加」ボタンを非表示にするにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

以下のコードでは5行を超えても「明細を追加」ボタンが表示されたままで、まだ行を追加することができてしまいます。以下のRailsのコードではなく、HTMLとjQuery(JavaScript)のサンプルでも問題ありませんので、アドバイス頂きたいです。宜しくお願い致します。

```
$(function() {
   function check_content() {
      if($('#costs_form_area .nested-fields').length == 5) {
           $('.specification_btn a.add_fields').hide();
      } else {
          $('.specification_btn a.add_fields').show();
      }
   }
});

<div id="costs_form_area">
  <%= f.fields_for :costs do |costs_form| %>
    <%= render 'cost_fields', f: costs_form %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="text-center specification_btn">
    <%= link_to_add_association '明細を追加', f, :costs, class: 'add_fields' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `check_content` 関数が呼ばれるのは、ページの読み込み完了時ではなく、「明細を追加」処理の後であるべきだと思います。また、実行がページ読み込み完了の時であっても、関数を呼び出す形にする必要があります。

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
   function check_content() {
      if($('#costs_form_area .nested-fields').length == 5) {
           $('.specification_btn a.add_fields').hide();
      } else {
          $('.specification_btn a.add_fields').show();
      }
   }
});
```

だと無名関数の中で関数を定義しただけなので、
実行するには

```
$(function() {
   (function check_content() {
      if($('#costs_form_area .nested-fields').length == 5) {
           $('.specification_btn a.add_fields').hide();
      } else {
          $('.specification_btn a.add_fields').show();
      }
   })();
});
```

のようにするか

```
$(function() {
    if($('#costs_form_area .nested-fields').length == 5) {
        $('.specification_btn a.add_fields').hide();
    } else {
        $('.specification_btn a.add_fields').show();
    }
});
```

のようにする必要があります。